# Paragraph aligning and box issue

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm looking for a cool "boxy" effect on my website. I managed to get two boxes on the same line, but, unfortunately, my `display: inline-table`, I believe, prevents me to give that effect.

EFFECT DESIRED: I want the text blocks to be in two columns but I don't want them to be line by line like they are right now.

PROBLEM: They're aligning instead of just stacking to the bottom.

EXTREMELY IMPORTANT: I don't recommend you run the snippet because, as it's designed for a wide screen it won't display as shown.

This is how it looks on my computer screen.

[image: They're aligned not stacking in two columns]

Does anyone know the answer to this?

I don't mind changing all of my set - up as long as I have the desired pattern.

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: #2b2b2a;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* NOTE: CLASSES */

.nav-bar {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f05ce8, #2aeceb);
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.main-title {
  font-family: Futura;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  margin: 8px;
  position: fixed;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 2% !important;
  margin: 0px 1%;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.vline {
  font-size: 28px;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  top: 10%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  height: 80%;
}

.nav-link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 57px;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right:50%;
  background:white;
  transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;
}

.nav-link:hover::before,.nav-link.active:before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.nav-selected::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: white;
  top: 57px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.text-square {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0px 2.2%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  display: inline-table;
}

.title-1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.insquare {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="./Database/CSS/styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Bac 2018</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- NOTE: NAV BAR -->
    <nav class="nav-bar">
      <a class="main-title">PLANS DU BAC</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="./Database/Pages/plus.html">Plus</a><a class="vline"></a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="./Database/Pages/cours.html">Cours</a><a class="vline"></a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="./Database/Pages/plans.html">Plans</a><a class="vline"></a>
      <a class="nav-link nav-selected" href="#">Accueil</a><a class="vline"></a>
    </nav><br><br><br><br><br>
    <!-- NOTE: Explanations -->
    <div class="text-square">
      <p class="title-1">COURS</p><br>
      <p class="insquare">Cette section regroupe les principaux cours de l'année. Tout ce qui est notions, objets d'études ou en relation avec l'oral se retrouve dans cette section.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-square">
      <p class="title-1">PLANS</p><br>
      <p class="insquare">Cette section regroupe tout les plans des oeuvres ou extraits vu en lecture analytique en français et littérature. Elle comporte quelques documents vu en lecture cursive ainsi que des résumés des oeuvres vu en classe.</p><p class="insquare">Il est possible que certaines fiches contiennent des erreurs, idem pour les résumés d'oeuvres ou de documents en lecture cursive. Donc si vous voyez une erreur ou une information qui manque, envoyez moi un mail : <a href="mailto:miloertas@gmail.com?subject=Erreur%20Fiche%20Bac" style="text-decoration: underline; color: DeepSkyBlue;">miloertas@gmail.com</a>, ça évitera que tout le monde apprennent un truc faux...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-square">
      <p class="title-1">PLANS</p><br>
      <p class="insquare">Cette section regroupe tout les plans des oeuvres ou extraits vu en lecture analytique en français et littérature. Elle comporte quelques documents vu en lecture cursive ainsi que des résumés des oeuvres vu en classe.</p><p class="insquare">Il est possible que certaines fiches contiennent des erreurs, idem pour les résumés d'oeuvres ou de documents en lecture cursive. Donc si vous voyez une erreur ou une information qui manque, envoyez moi un mail : <a href="mailto:miloertas@gmail.com?subject=Erreur%20Fiche%20Bac" style="text-decoration: underline; color: DeepSkyBlue;">miloertas@gmail.com</a>, ça évitera que tout le monde apprennent un truc faux...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-square">
      <p class="title-1">PLANS</p><br>
      <p class="insquare">Cette section regroupe tout les plans des oeuvres ou extraits vu en lecture analytique en français et littérature. Elle comporte quelques documents vu en lecture cursive ainsi que des résumés des oeuvres vu en classe.</p><p class="insquare">Il est possible que certaines fiches contiennent des erreurs, idem pour les résumés d'oeuvres ou de documents en lecture cursive. Donc si vous voyez une erreur ou une information qui manque, envoyez moi un mail : <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline; color: DeepSkyBlue;">miloertas@gmail.com</a>, ça évitera que tout le monde apprennent un truc faux...</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: People can run the snippet and click "Full page" to better see the problem.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in my browser. I'll check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use columns.

Basically, I put the text-squares in a container with two columns.

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: #2b2b2a;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* NOTE: CLASSES */

.nav-bar {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f05ce8, #2aeceb);
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.main-title {
  font-family: Futura;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  margin: 8px;
  position: fixed;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 2% !important;
  margin: 0px 1%;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.vline {
  font-size: 28px;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  top: 10%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  height: 80%;
}

.nav-link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 57px;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  background: white;
  transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;
}

.nav-link:hover::before,
.nav-link.active:before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.nav-selected::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: white;
  top: 57px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.text-square {        /* Note: changed styles */
  /*width: 45%;*/
  margin: 0px 2.2%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  /*display: inline-table;*/
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.title-1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

.insquare {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main {               /* new */
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<!-- NOTE: NAV BAR -->
<nav class="nav-bar">
  <a class="main-title">PLANS DU BAC</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="./Database/Pages/plus.html">Plus</a>
  <a class="vline"></a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="./Database/Pages/cours.html">Cours</a>
  <a class="vline"></a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="./Database/Pages/plans.html">Plans</a>
  <a class="vline"></a>
  <a class="nav-link nav-selected" href="#">Accueil</a>
  <a class="vline"></a>
</nav><br><br><br><br><br>
<!-- NOTE: Explanations -->
<div class="main">
  <div class="text-square">
    <p class="title-1">COURS</p><br>
    <p class="insquare">Cette section regroupe les principaux cours de l'année. Tout ce qui est notions, objets d'études ou en relation avec l'oral se retrouve dans cette section.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-square">
    <p class="title-1">PLANS</p><br>
    <p class="insquare">Cette section regroupe tout les plans des oeuvres ou extraits vu en lecture analytique en français et littérature. Elle comporte quelques documents vu en lecture cursive ainsi que des résumés des oeuvres vu en classe.</p>
    <p class="insquare">Il est possible que certaines fiches contiennent des erreurs, idem pour les résumés d'oeuvres ou de documents en lecture cursive. Donc si vous voyez une erreur ou une information qui manque, envoyez moi un mail : <a href="mailto:miloertas@gmail.com?subject=Erreur%20Fiche%20Bac"
        style="text-decoration: underline; color: DeepSkyBlue;">miloertas@gmail.com</a>, ça évitera que tout le monde apprennent un truc faux...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-square">
    <p class="title-1">PLANS</p><br>
    <p class="insquare">Cette section regroupe tout les plans des oeuvres ou extraits vu en lecture analytique en français et littérature. Elle comporte quelques documents vu en lecture cursive ainsi que des résumés des oeuvres vu en classe.</p>
    <p class="insquare">Il est possible que certaines fiches contiennent des erreurs, idem pour les résumés d'oeuvres ou de documents en lecture cursive. Donc si vous voyez une erreur ou une information qui manque, envoyez moi un mail : <a href="mailto:miloertas@gmail.com?subject=Erreur%20Fiche%20Bac"
        style="text-decoration: underline; color: DeepSkyBlue;">miloertas@gmail.com</a>, ça évitera que tout le monde apprennent un truc faux...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-square">
    <p class="title-1">PLANS</p><br>
    <p class="insquare">Cette section regroupe tout les plans des oeuvres ou extraits vu en lecture analytique en français et littérature. Elle comporte quelques documents vu en lecture cursive ainsi que des résumés des oeuvres vu en classe.</p>
    <p class="insquare">Il est possible que certaines fiches contiennent des erreurs, idem pour les résumés d'oeuvres ou de documents en lecture cursive. Donc si vous voyez une erreur ou une information qui manque, envoyez moi un mail : <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline; color: DeepSkyBlue;">miloertas@gmail.com</a>,
      ça évitera que tout le monde apprennent un truc faux...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea double checked and it works well in chrome but not in safari. Any fix in mind ?

Comment: Oh... I don't have a Mac, so I can't test Safari. It works well in Firefox and IE11 though. Let's hope someone can come up with a solution for Safari.

Comment: Ok don't worry, this has been really helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

If I fully understand what you want to achieve, just change your .text-square styles to:

```
.text-square {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0px 2.2% 2.2%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Well it works but the not the way I expected, I was unclear. I want the elements to stack up from the top the bottom and not from bottom to top if you see what I mean

Comment: So I tried other values for your `vertical-align` thing, but it doesnt seem to work...

Comment: Ah, now I see. Sorry for misleading you.